# Combine properties within an array

Tags: javascript

How can I combine the `firstName` and `lastName` properties in this array into a single `name` property separated by a space?

```
employeeNames = [ { firstName: "Collin", lastName: "Sexton" }, { firstName: "Darius", lastName: "Garland" } ]
```

Expected result:

```
someArray = [ { name: "Collin Sexton" }, { name: "Darius Garland" } ]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: `employeeNames.map(p => ({name: \`${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}\`}))`

Answer (score 1):

You should `map` through array.

```
const someArray = employeeNames.map(({ firstName, lastName }) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

enjoy

```js
(()=>{

    employeeNames = [{
        firstName: "Collin",
        lastName: "Sexton"
    },{
        firstName: "Darius",
        lastName: "Garland"
    }];

    let someArray = [];
    for (let item of employeeNames){
        let newItem = {
            name: item.firstName+' '+item.lastName,
        };
        someArray.push(newItem);
    }

    console.log(someArray);

})();
```